# Docker COPY/ADD no longer copies differences?

Tags: docker

For a long time, I've built an app using Docker with an intermediate container e.g. I'd build `myapp:base` which has all the core files copied:

```
FROM ubuntu:17.10
ADD app /app
```

Now, the main container `myapp:release` might be created simply with this

```
 FROM myapp:base 
 ADD app /app
```

A handful of files might be modified in the `app` directory, and I'd wind up with a small extra layer.

Recently though, this final `ADD` has resulted in a much larger layer, and I suspect it's related to a Docker update (I'm using Docker version 18.02.0-ce, build fc4de44)

Has something changed in how Docker figures out what's different? How can I get back to an efficient build which just has a small number of updated files in a layer?

### Steps to reproduce:

```
# make a dummy dir with a 64kb file in it

mkdir -p files
truncate -s 64k files/64k.file

# base container has a copy of the files

cat << EOF > Dockerfile.base
FROM ubuntu:16.04
COPY files/ /root/
EOF

# derived container should just have any updates

cat << EOF > Dockerfile.derived
FROM q899941:base
COPY files/ /root/
EOF

# build them....

docker build --file Dockerfile.base -t  q899941:base .
docker build --file Dockerfile.derived -t  q899941:derived .

# now let's review the layers

docker history q899941:derived
```

I get this result

```
IMAGE               CREATED                  CREATED BY                                      SIZE  
4e1eb5168d55        Less than a second ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY dir:8e20ede288278c71e…   65.5kB
022626ac5cf0        Less than a second ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY dir:8e20ede288278c71e…   65.5kB
0458a4468cbc        5 weeks ago              /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["/bin/bash"]            0B    
<missing>           5 weeks ago              /bin/sh -c mkdir -p /run/systemd && echo 'do…   7B    
<missing>           5 weeks ago              /bin/sh -c sed -i 's/^#\s*\(deb.*universe\)$…   2.76kB
<missing>           5 weeks ago              /bin/sh -c rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*          0B    
<missing>           5 weeks ago              /bin/sh -c set -xe   && echo '#!/bin/sh' > /…   745B  
<missing>           5 weeks ago              /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:a3344b835ea6fdc56…   112MB
```

The top layer is 64kb even though no files changed.

Comment: Looks like my issue was caused by overlay2 storage driver - I got the expected behaviour with the overlay storage driver. See https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/21950#issuecomment-208881571

I *think* I could get away with a build server running overlay for now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is a [known issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/21950), but not one that enough people care about!

- [Is there a way to add only changed files to a docker image as a new layer - without resorting to docker commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36553502/is-there-a-way-to-add-only-changed-files-to-a-docker-image-as-a-new-layer-with) is a StackOverflow question which covers the same ground.
- It seems the behaviour I expected worked with the overlay storage driver, but after some system updates I started using overlay2 which will copy all files into a layer and not just changed ones
- While one solution would be revert to overlay, it seems to pretty strongly deprecated at this point. [An alternative method to build 'diff' layers is detailed here](https://github.com/neam/docker-diff-based-layers)

I ended up doing a simple thing mentioned in one of the [comments](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/21950#issuecomment-273724244) in the bug report:

```
#clean up any previous attempt...

docker rm -f uniquename 2> /dev/null

# now take your base container, mount the updated dir as /src 
# then rsync from /src to the target dir - only updated files will
# actually be written, and we use --delete to ensure removed files are
# taken out...

docker run --name uniquename \
    -v ~/repo/mycode:/src \
    ${REPO}/${IMAGE}:${BASE} \
        rsync -ar --no-owner --no-group \
        --exclude-from '/src/.dockerignore' --delete \
        /src/ /app/

# we can commit that updated container with a tag 

docker commit uniquename ${REPO}/${IMAGE}:${NEW_TAG}
```

One more thing - this solution appeared to wipe out the existing `CMD` which provided my containers default startup command. So after adding this diff layer, I had another Dockerfile to create a container from the 'diff' build above with the `CMD` added back in.